# Only load React compontent on some pages with react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have a ReactJS component that I want to mount to `#test-scores` on `user/show.html`.
The component lives in `app/assets/javascripts/react-components/test-score.js.jsx`.

How can I make sure it's only loaded when the user visits `user/show`?
It is loaded for every page as it is now.

**app/assets/javascripts/react-components.js:**

```
//= require_tree ./react-components
```

**app/assets/javascripts/react-components/test-score.js.jsx**

```
  1 $( document ).ready( function()  {
  2
  3   var TestResultBox = React.createClass({
  4     loadTestScoreFromServer: function() {
  5       $.ajax({
  [snipp...]
 74   React.render(
 75     <TestResultBox />,
 76     document.getElementById('test-scores')
 77   );
```

This results in a JS error that breaks other things:

```
react.js?body=1:20238 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation:
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Any suggestions to how I should structure things? :-)

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "good error", because it let’s you know that the node doesn’t exist in the DOM before you try to access it. You can easily check if the node exists first, something like:

```
var scores = document.getElementById('test-scores')
if ( scores ) {
    React.render(<TestResultBox />, scores);
}
```

jQuery have a bad habit of silenting errors, but if you would like to use jQuery instead, something like this would work:

```
$('#test-scores').each(function() {
    React.render(<TestResultBox />, this);
})
```